# Encrypt/Decrypt file. ASCII +1 for encryption/decryption

Tags: java, encryption, file-io, ascii

I'm trying to read in a file of text, and "encrypt"/convert each letter to +1 from the ASCII table (I also want to "decrypt" so -1 for that). So "a" will become "b", "b" to "c" and so forth. I only need to convert alphabetic letters (Ignore everything else, print them as is). I'm having troubles with this part of the code:

```
        for(int i = 0; i <= words.size(); i++)
        {                
            for(int j = 0; j <= words.get(i).length(); j++)
            {
                char ch = ' ';
                ch = words.get(i).charAt(j);
                ch += 1;                    
                morewords.add(ch);
            }              
            fileOut.print(morewords.get(i)  + " ");
        }
```

I've figured out how to +1 the char, but I'm not sure how to add that back in to an array or print it out correctly (Since "morewords.add(ch)" is only going to add the char, instead of converting all the chars an adding a string). The "words.get(i).length()" takes the entire length of the array "words", when I just want the length of the string @ position "i" in the array, so it throws an error since the length of the array is longer than the string word. I've been stuck on this for hours and I cannot figure it out. I'm thinking maybe I shouldn't read them in as strings and should have read them in as chars and this might have all been simpler?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Character> morewords = new ArrayList<Character>();
        String fileName = ""; //Replace Test with this
        File f;
        Scanner fileIn;

        System.out.println("Please enter a file name for encryption: ");
        //fileName = in.nextLine();
        fileName = "Test.txt";


        try
        {
            //Build the file and attach a scanner to it
            f = new File (fileName); 
            fileIn = new Scanner (f);            

            System.out.println(f.exists()); //For errors
            int counting = 0;

            //Reads in indvidual strings. 
            for(counting =0; fileIn.hasNext(); counting++)
            {                
                words.add(fileIn.next());
                System.out.println(words);
            }            

            PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter ("Backwards.txt");

            for(int i = 0; i <= words.size(); i++)
            {                
                for(int j = 0; j <= words.get(i).length(); j++)
                {
                    char ch = ' ';
                    ch = words.get(i).charAt(j);
                    ch += 1;                    
                    morewords.add(ch);
                }              
                fileOut.print(morewords.get(i)  + " ");
            }            

            fileOut.close();            

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find file");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Based on Andrea's answer this seems like a typo. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in a for loops is right to do

```
for (int i = 0; i <= words.size()-1; i++){}
```

if you'r starting at 0 you end at length-1

what i have changed is

```
PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter("C:/Backwards.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i <= words.size()-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= words.get(i).length()-1; j++)
            {
                char ch = ' ';
                ch = words.get(i).charAt(j);
                ch ++; // +=1
                morewords.add(ch);
                fileOut.print(ch);
            }
            fileOut.print(" ");
        }

        fileOut.close();
```

and it output right if i have understood right =)

this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader inChannel = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/script.txt"));
    BufferedWriter outChannel = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/output.txt"));
    String toParse = "";
    while ( (toParse = inChannel.readLine()) != null )
    {
        String toWrite = "";
        for(int i=0; i!=toParse.length();i++)
        {
            char c = toParse.charAt(i);
            if(true) //check if must be encoded or not
            {
                c++;
                toWrite += c;
            }
        }
        outChannel.write(toWrite);
        outChannel.newLine();
    }       
    inChannel.close();
    outChannel.close();
}
```

hope helped

Comment: That did help, thank you! Adding the -1 to words.size() fixed the problem. Also, thanks for showing me a much easier and shorter way to do it!